# How can I overlap the saved cards on each other with front card being little tilted so user can understand there are more cards behind it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-cardview

I am saving the items and displaying them in cards where the cards are overlapping each other but there is no way user will know that there are more than cards below the front card. I want below card to tilt a bit or front card. I have achieved this in jetpack compose using . rotate but I am unaware of this in traditonal XML layouts. Following is my class.
ToLearnFlashCards.kt

```
class ToLearnFlashCards : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding:FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding
    lateinit var bottomNav:BottomNavigationView
    val cardViewmodel:  FlashCardViewmodel by viewModels{
        WordViewModelFactory((requireActivity().application as MyApp).repository)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentToLearnFlashCardsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)

        //Taking the bOTTOMNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
        bottomNav = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        binding.backIcon.setOnClickListener {
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_toLearnFlashCards_to_flashCards)
        }

        val adapter = FlashcardpaiAdapter{cardPair->
            cardViewmodel.deleteCards(cardPair)
        }
        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        //Observe  the data changes for the items added
        cardViewmodel.allWords.observe(requireActivity()) { cardPairs ->

            for (cardpair in cardPairs) {
                adapter.submitList(cardPairs)
            }

        }


        return binding.root
    }

}
```

The xml layout files associated with it .

fragment_to_learn_flash_cards.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recycle_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

recycle_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/word1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/word2"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageDelete"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_delete_24"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, How can i overlap all the saved cards?